# Installation of hpbandster and ConfigSpace failed

Tags: pip, python-3.7, ubuntu-18.04

I created a virtual environment using `virtualenv venv -p python3` and `source venv/bin/activate` under Ubuntu 18.04. Then I tried to install [hpbandster](https://pypi.org/project/hpbandster/) which installes [ConfigSpace](https://pypi.org/project/ConfigSpace/#description) as requirement. The installation of ConfigSpace failes throwing the following error:

```
Building wheel for ConfigSpace (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-aa1hsmn9
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/
  Complete output (33 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
  copying ConfigSpace/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
  copying ConfigSpace/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
  copying ConfigSpace/__version__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/pcs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/irace.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/pcs_new.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/exception.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/cycles.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/dag.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/classes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/classes/digraph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/classes/graph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components
  copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components/strongly_connected.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components
  running build_ext
  building 'ConfigSpace.hyperparameters' extension
  error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.pyx')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ConfigSpace
  Running setup.py clean for ConfigSpace
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/netifaces/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/netifaces/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-c5zv0th0
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/netifaces/
  Complete output (20 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  checking for getifaddrs...found.
  checking for getnameinfo...found.
  checking for IPv6 socket IOCTLs...not found.
  checking for optional header files...netash/ash.h netatalk/at.h netax25/ax25.h neteconet/ec.h netipx/ipx.h netpacket/packet.h netrose/rose.h linux/irda.h linux/atm.h linux/llc.h linux/tipc.h linux/dn.h.
  checking whether struct sockaddr has a length field...no.
  checking which sockaddr_xxx structs are defined...at ax25 in in6 ipx un rose ash ec ll atmpvc atmsvc dn irda llc.
  checking for routing socket support...no.
  checking for sysctl(CTL_NET...) support...no.
  checking for netlink support...yes.
  will use netlink to read routing table
  building 'netifaces' extension
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.10.9 -DHAVE_GETIFADDRS=1 -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO=1 -DHAVE_NETASH_ASH_H=1 -DHAVE_NETATALK_AT_H=1 -DHAVE_NETAX25_AX25_H=1 -DHAVE_NETECONET_EC_H=1 -DHAVE_NETIPX_IPX_H=1 -DHAVE_NETPACKET_PACKET_H=1 -DHAVE_NETROSE_ROSE_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_IRDA_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_ATM_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_LLC_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_TIPC_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_DN_H=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_AT=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_AX25=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IN=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IPX=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_UN=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ROSE=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ASH=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_EC=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LL=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ATMPVC=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ATMSVC=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_DN=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IRDA=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LLC=1 -DHAVE_PF_NETLINK=1 -I/home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netifaces.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netifaces.o
  netifaces.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
   #include <Python.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
  Running setup.py clean for netifaces
Failed to build ConfigSpace netifaces
Installing collected packages: cython, ConfigSpace, pytz, pandas, patsy, statsmodels, serpent, Pyro4, netifaces, hpbandster
    Running setup.py install for ConfigSpace ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-c6j8cu8m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/include/site/python3.7/ConfigSpace
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/
    Complete output (46 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
    copying ConfigSpace/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
    copying ConfigSpace/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
    copying ConfigSpace/__version__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
    copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
    copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/pcs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
    copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/irace.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
    copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
    copying ConfigSpace/read_and_write/pcs_new.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/read_and_write
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/exception.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/cycles.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/dag.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/classes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/classes/digraph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/classes/graph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/classes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components
    copying ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components/strongly_connected.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/nx/algorithms/components
    running build_ext
    cythoning ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.pyx to ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.c
    skipping 'ConfigSpace/forbidden.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'ConfigSpace/conditions.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'ConfigSpace/c_util.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    cythoning ConfigSpace/util.pyx to ConfigSpace/util.c
    skipping 'ConfigSpace/configuration_space.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'ConfigSpace.hyperparameters' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.o
    ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.c:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lp6jkyvm/ConfigSpace/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-c6j8cu8m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/anonymous/Documents/some_folder/venv/include/site/python3.7/ConfigSpace Check the logs for full command output.
```

I do not have sudo permission so I have to keep using Python 3.7.5. What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.pyx')

There is a bug report [130](https://github.com/automl/ConfigSpace/issues/130), still open. The package seems to be broken and is not `pip`-installable.

Try to install Cython:

```
pip install Cython
pip install ConfigSpace
```

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file

You should install Python development/header files. Without superuser access install them from Python source code and direct compiler to use your local headers.

Comment: ```pip install ConfigSpace``` causes the same problems. Seems like it is a dependency of HpBandSter. Do you have a tutorial for installing it without superuser rights? Those headers belong to [python-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-dev), right?

Comment: Perhaps extracting them from Python source distribution could be enough.